Fixing issue with robots after upgrading packages?
After updating ros-humble version and other packages (navigation2, etc.) on the robots, they now do not respond to movement, not executing plans after setting initial pose and when also setting manual goals (it says "navigate_to_pose action server is not available. is the initial pose set").
There are some warnings regarding QoS settings, such as on the odom topic where the publisher is on best effort and the subscriber is on reliable, though I am not sure if this is the root of the issue.
Here is the log of the start up:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2024-09-13-00-59-57-447083-burne-9751
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [9764]
[INFO] [component_container_isolated-2]: process started with pid [9766]
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189203.353688939] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/install/nav2_map_server/lib/libmap_server_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.003871732] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_map_server::CostmapFilterInfoServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.004088082] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_map_server::MapSaver>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.004157784] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_map_server::MapServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.004217191] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_map_server::MapServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.066045416] [map_server]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    map_server lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.066326302] [map_server]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/map_server' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.070390274] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/install/nav2_controller/lib/libcontroller_server_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.246343390] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_controller::ControllerServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.246515351] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_controller::ControllerServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.285039155] [controller_server]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    controller_server lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.481431557] [controller_server]: Creating controller server
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.529185201] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    local_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.560351662] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/controller_server' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.582602410] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/install/nav2_amcl/lib/libamcl_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.658735898] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_amcl::AmclNode>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.658914581] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_amcl::AmclNode>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.697430107] [amcl]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    amcl lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.713330242] [amcl]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/amcl' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.748293790] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libsmoother_server_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.790984472] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_smoother::SmootherServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.791160285] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_smoother::SmootherServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.831733251] [smoother_server]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    smoother_server lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.856366453] [smoother_server]: Creating smoother server
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/smoother_server' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.866898093] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/install/nav2_lifecycle_manager/lib/libnav2_lifecycle_manager_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.890049201] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_lifecycle_manager::LifecycleManager>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.890209162] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_lifecycle_manager::LifecycleManager>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.928209583] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/lifecycle_manager_localization' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.974604316] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mCreating and initializing lifecycle service clients[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.978000703] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libplanner_server_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.997556296] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_planner::PlannerServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189204.997882941] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_planner::PlannerServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.011210660] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mStarting managed nodes bringup...[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.011566341] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mConfiguring map_server[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.013435357] [map_server]: Configuring
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/src/spl_packages/localization_server/maps/humanise2.yaml
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -8.99
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -13.8
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.25
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.047911651] [planner_server]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    planner_server lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/src/spl_packages/localization_server/maps/humanise2.pgm
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.075976110] [planner_server]: Creating
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.120303941] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    global_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.126980310] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/planner_server' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.155444061] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libbehavior_server_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/src/spl_packages/localization_server/maps/humanise2.pgm: 648 X 441 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.270219093] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<behavior_server::BehaviorServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.270417498] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<behavior_server::BehaviorServer>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.284878926] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mConfiguring amcl[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.285391810] [amcl]: Configuring
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.285742231] [amcl]: initTransforms
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.342627123] [amcl]: initPubSub
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.355311146] [amcl]: Subscribed to map topic.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.375440548] [behavior_server]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    behavior_server lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.388765915] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mActivating map_server[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.389357630] [map_server]: Activating
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.390540061] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.391750881] [amcl]: Received a 648 X 441 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/behavior_server' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.473796265] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libbt_navigator_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.510526664] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Server map_server connected with bond.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.510720606] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mActivating amcl[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.511717687] [amcl]: Activating
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.511917518] [amcl]: Creating bond (amcl) to lifecycle manager.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.525963896] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_bt_navigator::BtNavigator>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.526662129] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_bt_navigator::BtNavigator>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.607178512] [bt_navigator]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    bt_navigator lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.607443972] [bt_navigator]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/bt_navigator' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.620169142] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libwaypoint_follower_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.638151735] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_waypoint_follower::WaypointFollower>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.638317900] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_waypoint_follower::WaypointFollower>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.651859005] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Server amcl connected with bond.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.652007967] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mManaged nodes are active[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.652075410] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: [34m[1mCreating bond timer...[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.694462689] [waypoint_follower]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    waypoint_follower lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.713378196] [waypoint_follower]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/waypoint_follower' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.738961295] [nav2_container]: Load Library: /home/ubuntu/ros2_ws/install/nav2_velocity_smoother/lib/libvelocity_smoother_core.so
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.767277270] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_velocity_smoother::VelocitySmoother>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.767543508] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_velocity_smoother::VelocitySmoother>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.828741092] [velocity_smoother]: 
[component_container_isolated-2]    velocity_smoother lifecycle node launched. 
[component_container_isolated-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/velocity_smoother' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.837992487] [nav2_container]: Found class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_lifecycle_manager::LifecycleManager>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.838136911] [nav2_container]: Instantiate class: rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<nav2_lifecycle_manager::LifecycleManager>
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.882549445] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating
[INFO] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Loaded node '/lifecycle_manager_navigation' in container '/nav2_container'
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.902715105] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: [34m[1mCreating and initializing lifecycle service clients[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.945285900] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: [34m[1mStarting managed nodes bringup...[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.945533693] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: [34m[1mConfiguring controller_server[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.946112872] [controller_server]: Configuring controller interface
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.946885382] [controller_server]: getting goal checker plugins..
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.947446375] [controller_server]: Controller frequency set to 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.947654317] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Configuring
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189205.963535841] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "voxel_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.094760464] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.136258623] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "voxel_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.136474787] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.144696138] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.184801424] [controller_server]: Created progress_checker : progress_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.194097133] [controller_server]: Created goal checker : general_goal_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.198607064] [controller_server]: Controller Server has general_goal_checker  goal checkers available.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.214522106] [controller_server]: Created controller : FollowPath of type nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.267545412] [controller_server]: Controller Server has FollowPath  controllers available.
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189206.317724157] [controller_server]: New publisher discovered on topic '/odom', offering incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.318034969] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: [34m[1mConfiguring smoother_server[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.318616981] [smoother_server]: Configuring smoother server
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.352450189] [smoother_server]: Created smoother : simple_smoother of type nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.361092091] [smoother_server]: Smoother Server has simple_smoother  smoothers available.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.386832448] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: [34m[1mConfiguring planner_server[0m[0m
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.387330683] [planner_server]: Configuring
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.387500885] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Configuring
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.409693911] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.423439551] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.429743387] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.429895570] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.443553119] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.465571703] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.465746942] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.468746278] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.496613925] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 648 X 441 at 0.050000 m/pix
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189206.533573135] [planner_server]: Created global planner plugin GridBased of type nav2_straightline_planner/StraightLine
[component_container_isolated-2] [ERROR] [1726189206.543306895] [planner_server]: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[component_container_isolated-2] [ERROR] [1726189206.543487134] [planner_server]: Original error: std::bad_alloc
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189206.543607725] [planner_server]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[component_container_isolated-2] [FATAL] [1726189206.543699076] [planner_server]: Lifecycle node planner_server does not have error state implemented
[component_container_isolated-2] [ERROR] [1726189206.544822804] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to change state for node: planner_server
[component_container_isolated-2] [ERROR] [1726189206.544965062] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189208.629823047] [amcl]: createLaserObject
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189208.791003848] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189210.828271836] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189212.903788538] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189213.284442018] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189213.284923383] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189214.991624675] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189215.839585817] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189217.067118840] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189217.264714377] [amcl]: New subscription discovered on topic '/particle_cloud', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189218.506058003] [rviz2]: Trying to create a map of size 648 x 441 using 1 swatches
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726189218.527146356] [rviz2]: Vertex Program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.vert Fragment Program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.frag GLSL link result : 
[rviz2-1] active samplers with a different type refer to the same texture image unit
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189219.144205451] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189221.219283862] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189223.295323298] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189225.371100294] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189227.446634922] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189229.521770739] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189231.609801726] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189233.685680794] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189235.761132626] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189237.836415350] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189239.912943929] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.625806974] [rviz2]: Setting estimate pose: Frame:map, Position(0.0437501, 0.00937487, 0), Orientation(0, 0, 0.0474561, 0.998873) = Angle: 0.0949478
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189240.627082460] [amcl]: initialPoseReceived
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1726189240.628168188] [amcl]: Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1726189240.627654 but the latest data is at time 1726189240.591563, when looking up transform from frame [base_footprint] to frame [odom])
[component_container_isolated-2] [INFO] [1726189240.628441741] [amcl]: Setting pose (1726189240.628433): 0.044 0.009 0.095
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.717365269] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189217.326 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.717815690] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189217.841 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.718011558] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189222.386 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.718155408] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189226.673 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.718283444] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189227.582 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189240.718385850] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189229.522 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189243.871610163] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189233.809 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189244.122257636] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189234.067 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] Start navigation
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189246.072547684] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189236.019 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189249.969252824] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189239.913 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726189250.369453915] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'rplidar_link' at time 1726189240.306 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726189250.828689726] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: navigate_to_pose action server is not available. Is the initial pose set?
[rviz2-1] Start navigation
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726189293.349207905] [rviz_navigation_dialog_action_client]: navigate_to_pose action server is not available. Is the initial pose set?
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726189293.495836983] [rviz2]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1726189282.998352 but the earliest data is at time 1726189283.392946, when looking up transform from frame [rplidar_link] to frame [map]

